# Извлечь нужный текст из разметки HTML

Tags: android, html, java

Привет. Помогите разобраться, как вытащить текст `<td>Облачно, дымка</td>` из полученного ниже кода, естественно, без приставок `<td>`:

```
<dl class="cloudness">
    <dt class="png" title="Облачно, дымка" style="background-image: url(http://s2.gismeteo.ua/static/images/icons/new/n.moon.c3.png)"><br /></dt>
    <dd><table><tr><td>Облачно, дымка</td></tr></table></dd>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, с помощью [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/)

```
String html = "<dl class=\"cloudness\"><dt class=\"png\" title=\"Облачно, дымка\" style=\"background-image: url(http://s2.gismeteo.ua/static/images/icons/new/n.moon.c3.png)\"><br /></dt><dd><table><tr><td>Облачно, дымка</td></tr></table></dd></dl>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

Elements columns = doc.select("td");

String desiredText = columns.first().text();
```

Comment: ахахах, спасибо, вот это я дурак)  сам же с помощью юсупа парсил :)

Большое спасибо :)

Только на всякий случай мне еще интресны другие варианты.

Comment: @djbolya: Никаких других вариантов, по сути, нет. В любом случае вы берёте парсер HTML и парсите, потом выбираете нужное из полученной объектной модели (ну или реагируете на SAX-события, зависит от парсера). Регулярки — метод набивания шишек, не пользуйтесь ими для разбора сложных языков типа HTML.

Comment: spasibo bolshoe